# Why is Clostridium difficile toxin A + B outdated in snomed?

Tags: database, identifiers, data-management, ontology, bacteria

I'm looking at the new version of the Snomed dictionary and the concept `707993000` ***Clostridium difficile* toxin A + B (substance)** is deactivated (and outdated) since version `20170731`. Can anybody explain me, why this happened?

We have used this concept for coding of results of laboratory examinations in our software system. Is there an alternative Snomed concept usable for the purpose of coding of evidence of the Clostridium difficile toxin A + B ?